# Ruby Parameters

Tags: ruby

Could someone please explain lines 5 and 6?  On line 5, is `|word|` a parameter?  Why is it needed there?  Also, on line 6, are `{|a, b| b}` also parameters.  How should one read line 6?  What is it doing?

```
puts "Input something: "                     # 1
text = gets.chomp                            # 2
words = text.split                           # 3
frequencies = Hash.new(0)                    # 4
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 } # 5
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|a, b| b} # 6
frequencies.reverse!                         # 7
```

Comment: Ruby **is not** Ruby on rails.

Comment: Please read some ruby book, or get some ruby tutorial. Those methods (`each` and `sort_by`) are called iterators and they accept blocks of code as an argument. It is way to broad to tell you exactly how it works, but they are well explained in, well, every ruby guide.

Comment: `word` and `a, b` are called [block arguments](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument)

Comment: `x { |y| ... }` in Ruby is roughly equivalent to `x(function(y) { ... })` in JavaScript.

Comment: @user1741853 To quote [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers". A "professional" programmer would read a language tutorial where these things are explained on the first 10 pages...

Answer (score 2):

> On line 5, is `|word|` a parameter?

Yes, it's a [block argument](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument).

> Why is it needed there?

From [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each)'s documentation: *"Calls the given block once for each element in `self`, passing that element as a parameter."*

Example:

```
words = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
words.each { |word| puts word }
```

The block is called three times. On the first pass, its block argument `word` is set to `"foo"`, on the second pass it's set to `"bar"` and on the third pass it's set to `"baz"`. Each time `word` is printed using `puts`.

Output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

In your example, a hash is used to store the word frequencies. Within the `each` loop, the word's count is incremented.

> How should one read line 6? What is it doing?

[`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) sorts a collection by the block's result. For example, to sort an array of strings by the string's length you would use:

```
["xxx", "xx", "x"].sort_by { |str| str.length }
#=> ["x", "xx", "xxx"]
```

Since `frequencies` is a hash, the block is called for each *pair*. Therefore, two arguments are set - `a` is the pair's key and `b` is the pair's value:

```
frequencies = { "foo" => 3, "bar" => 2, "baz" => 1}
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |a, b| b }
#=> [["baz", 1], ["bar", 2], ["foo", 3]]
```

It sorts the hash by its values. Note that `sort_by` returns an array. The array is assigned to the `frequencies` variable.

Instead of `a` and `b` you could use more descriptive argument names:

```
frequencies.sort_by { |word, count| count }
```